# Rails & AcitveRecord Optimization: Should I use AJAX to get objects one at a time or load 20 at once and use JQuery to show/hide

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, activerecord

I only want to show the user one object at a time but they can click "next" to view the next object. I have 20 objects.

**Option 1:**

Load all 20 objects in the backend and use JQuery to do all the hide/show work.

**Option 2:**

Load 1 object and use AJAX to get the next object when it's needed

Things to consider:

- The objects themselves are very lightweight, just text and small images
- The ActiveRecord query to get the objects is somewhat complex (not sure how much of a difference that makes). Here it is for reference:

  ```
       Event.where(approved: true)
            .where("date > ?", from_date)
            .where("date < ?", until_date)
            .includes(:votes)
            .where("votes.user_id != ? OR votes.user_id IS NULL", user_id).references(:votes)
            .includes(:event_rankings)
            .where("event_rankings.user_id = ?", user_id).order("event_rankings.weighted_score DESC")
            .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
  ```

Which option is better?

Comment: You can clean that up quite a bit. `.where(date: [from_date..until_date])`. `where(event_rankings: { user_id: user_id } )`

Comment: ^^ First one looks good.. But the second one I actually need to get event_rankings where user_id is user_id OR null

Answer (score 0):

The connection overhead of loading one item at a time would IMO not make it worth it. So I would go with option 1.